# Laravel - Package can't recognise Auth functions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package

I made a package which is counting the visitors on a webpage. Currently I have a single route, controller and view which don't do very much other than display a simple string. I have a separate Laravel application where this package is specifically build for. In this separate application I have a layout file called backend.

`layouts/layouts/backend.blade.php`.

My package view is extending this template like so: (backend.blade.php does not exists in the package but in the separate laravel application of-course)

```
@extends('layouts.layouts.backend')

@section('content')
    <div class="container-fluid pt-5 ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3>{{ __('Visitors') }}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

The package successfully extends this layout but it can't find functions such as `Auth::user()->token` and it will say

```
Trying to get property 'token' of non-object (View: /Users/rainierlaan/Sites/rainierlaan/resources/views/layouts/layouts/backend.blade.php)
```

Why does this happen?

This is my packages service provider

```
 public function register()
    {
        // Controllers
        $this->app->make('Rainieren\Visitors\Http\Controllers\VisitorController');
        // Views
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/resources/views', 'visitors');
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/resources/views' => resource_path('views/visitors'),
        ]);
        // Migrations
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/database/migrations');
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        include __DIR__ . '/routes/routes.php';
    }
```

When I do `vendor:publish` the view successfully publishes to the right folder but somehow can't recognise functions such as `Auth::user()->token` or `Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->count())`

This is my package route:

```
<?php


Route::get('dashboard/visitors', '\Rainieren\Visitors\Http\Controllers\VisitorController@index')->name('visitors');
```

And this is the controller

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('visitors::index'); 
    }
```

Comment: when you do `vendor:publish` what are you expecting to get from `Auth::user()` ?? you're in CLI

Comment: I am expecting to get the user data from the application where the package is installed. If that is possible of course

Comment: which user ? no user is authenticated when you're in CLI commands

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would need a little bit more debugging information but my first assumption is the missing `AuthenticateSession` or `Authenticate` middleware.

Laravel defines a default middleware group `web` for your routes inside `routes/web.php` and this group uses the `AuthenticateSession` middleware. This is how a new installation looks like:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'web', <<< this is the magic part
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/web.php');
});
```

Here we see that the middleware group `web` is used.

In your custom module / service provider this is not the case. Your `Route::get()` definition is added to the `Router` but not inside this group. Therefore all necessary internals to authenticate the user are not performed.

In this scenario I would try to use `->middleware('auth')` or `->middleware('web')` which will use the main-projects group middleware.

```
Route::get('dashboard/visitors', '\Rainieren\Visitors\Http\Controllers\VisitorController@index')
  ->name('visitors')
  ->middleware('web');
```

Here is a different idea:

If you say you're always authenticated. Then you could try to move all `web` middlewares into the global middlewares within your `Kernel` (`protected $middleware = []`).

I did not tested this but I can imagine that this could work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen in all of my active packages that they don't use Auth class at all in the views.

Their workaround is using this in the controller and pass it to the view:

```
$user = auth()->user();

return view('folder.view' ,['user'=>$user]);
```

And then in the view:

```
{{$user->token}} <!-- OR --!> {{$user->unreadNotifications->count()}}
```

Obviously as @N69S has stated only if a user is authenticated this is going to work.

Hope this works!!

**EDIT:**(Sorry didn't understand well the first time)

The error is in your service provider class yo have to do all the logic on the boot function, not in the register, because if you do in the register function, you load all before the laravel framework (To say something)
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers#the-register-method

Your serviceprovider should end like this:

```
    public function register()
    {
        //Nothing
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Controllers
        $this->app->make('Rainieren\Visitors\Http\Controllers\VisitorController');
        // Views
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/resources/views', 'visitors');
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/resources/views' => resource_path('views/visitors'),
        ]);
        // Migrations
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/database/migrations');
        include __DIR__ . '/routes/routes.php';
    }
```

Hope this finally works!

Comment: The user is always authenticated but this means I can't do `Auth::user()` anymore in my main project layout? I don't know how to parse a variable in my main project. Because the code you stated above will be placed in my package. But my main projects layout still uses `Auth::user()`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missunderstood that part, so I think your fail is that you are doing all the logic in the register function, you should pass all that to the boot function, give me a second and i will edit my response with the clarification ;)

Comment: I moved everything over from the register method to the boot method but unfortunately this does not work. I still get the same error. What may cause this?